# iOS iTunes latest podcasts not showing up

Tags: itunes, ios, podcasts

On my iPod touch running iOS 4.1, the iTunes store app (purple note icon) lets me search for podcasts and download episodes. In my RSS feeds I often see a new podcast episode announced, so I load up the podcast in iTunes and inevitably the most recent episode is absent. Has anyone else experienced this problem, and are there any solutions to this? besides:

- use Instacast
- sync to PC/Mac iTunes
- wait a few days for it to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear this more and more. iTunes on the PC directly uses the RSS feed and can be downloaded immediately. The podcasts in the iTunes store are cached, meaning that a process has to go out and update it. You have no control over this. If you don't want to continuously sync with iTunes, get a podcast app for the iPod Touch. I like [Podcaster](http://podcaster.fm/) though there are many others. This app like all of the others uses the direct RSS feed and can pull down the show immediately.